# SQL transactions how to implement it in this scenario

Tags: sql, asp.net, transactions

I need to do something like the code below with SQL transaction but i dont know if this is the correct way to do it, and what parameters go in the  /* parameters */. If its not the way how do can i implement it?

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bool correct = true;

        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                using (SqlTransaction tr = cn.BeginTransaction())
                {
                 DoInsert(ref correct, /* paramaters */);
                 DoUpdate(ref correct, /* parameters */);
                 
                 if(correct)
                    tr.Commit();
                 else
                    tr.Rollback();
                }
            }
         }
    } 
protected void DoInsert(ref bool correct, /* parameters */)
    { 
      try{
           /* insert code */ 
         }
      catch{
            correct = false;
           }
      finally{
              cn.Close();
             }

    }
protected void DoUpdate(ref bool correct,/* parameters */)
    { 
      try{
           /* Update code */ 
         }
      catch{
            correct = false;
           }
      finally{
              cn.Close();
             }

    }
```

Comment: The actual parameter in DoUpdate() has the potential to override the prior result from DoInsert(). I think you should evaluate the result from DoInsert() prior to calling to DoUpdate().

Comment: Seems to me you just check RIGHT after the insert - if that don't work, then why bother trying to do some update and THEN do a roll back? Check the insert for a error, and if you have a error then I see zero reasons to go ahead with a update, and THEN check some value that told you the insert failed and then roll back things? Why not just simple check insert - if that don't work then for what reason would we continue with a update that only supposed to run if the insert worked? Seems to me the simple code flow is to check if the insert worked or not - and thus take the appropriate action then

Comment: Yes, thx for that. My point is about the transaction. is it ok that way? or it will not work at all? Do i need to pass the tr as parameters to de insert and update?